# Formatting with escape characters within Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping

I have spent some time searching but have not been able to find the answer that applied to my situation.

Basically, I have a datetime variable that I am trying to format as MM/dd/yyyy. Here is the statement I am using:

```
FORMAT(openDate, ''''MM\/dd\/yyyy'''')
```

The extra ' is due to the string I am writing to is inside another string. I beleive that the number of ' is not the issue as this statement works

```
ISNULL(openDate, ''''N/A'''')
```

But my return looks like the date time was converted to an int.

If I do this:

```
FORMAT(openDate, ''''MM\/dd\//yyyy'''')
```

then my return looks like

```
03/29//2002
```

Am I using the escape incorrectly? Why can I get one / between month and day, but not between day and year? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:  Found that my issue was within excel. I was giving it a date 12/5/2005 and it was taking it as division. Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: what is wrong with `FORMAT(openDate, ''''MM\/dd\/yyyy'''')` why you use doble `/ /` on the second one?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do the /'s need to be escaped at all in SQL?  This is MSSQL/TSQL?  Or is this SQL being generated in a language that requires it to be escaped (C/C#/C++)?

Comment: @KrisOye  Yes, this is interfacing with C# so it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  The reason I use the double // at the year part is because if I dont, my return is the date time converted to an int for some reason. With the double /, it is the formatted datetime variable.

Comment: I would probably challenge the quotes even though you believe they are OK - the integer you are getting in the first sample smells of division taking place as a result of the '/'-s - is that possible? Please note that same would not happen with string value 'N/A'. Also you are saying this is in C#, you should be able to track at which level (C# or SQL) is the issue happening - this is not clear now and opens space for wrong suggestions & speculations.

Comment: To help others help you, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as previously suggested.

Comment: you sure you're not overdoing it with the single quotes?.. `FORMAT(GETDATE(), ''MM/dd/yyyy'')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '20151113'
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Result:

```
13/11/2015
```